# Fetch all records from MySQL as lazy="false" with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, smarty, smarty3

I have 2 tables in my database users and users_roles, like so:

users:

```
id | username | user_role_id
----------------------------
 1 | User1    | 1
 2 | User2    | 1
 3 | User3    | 2
```

users_roles:

```
id | role 
----------
 1 | admin
 2 | user
```

So, in Java I just had to write in Hibernate mappings an attribute lazy="false" to just get a list of all `users` automatically containing `users_roles` objects too, each specifically for each record in `users` table, but in PHP? I just came across an option in the PDO called `FETCH_ASSOC`, but I cannot understand how it works.

My get all users list method looks like this:

```
public function getAll() {

    $conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");

    $sql->execute();
    $list = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $conn = null;

    return $list;
}
```

and the piece of code from the Smarty template:

```
{foreach from=$usersList item=item}                
    {$item->username}
    {$item->users_roles.role}
{/foreach}
```

Would you mind helping me a little to get on the right way to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FETCH_ASSOC option fetches the rows into an associative array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => name1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => name2
        )
)
```

If you want top get all the users, who have a corresponding record in users_roles table, you can use this request:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    users
INNER JOIN
    users_roles
ON
    users_roles.id=users.user_role_id
ORDER BY
    users.id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, I just had to add `SELECT users.*, users_roles.*`. Working now .

Comment: @DenisHoss웃 Sorry, I thought, you need only the users data. You can just put a star into the columns specification.

Comment: Yeah, but for a better understanding I thought it would be better like  `users.*, users_roles.*`. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of PDO in Java is JDBC: you have statements and result sets, not business objects. Hibernate is an object-relational-mapping (ORM) library that allows mapping tables into business objects.

There are several ORMs for PHP, for example [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and [Propel](http://propelorm.org/). Search for "PHP ORM" on the Internet.

Or you can use plain SQL, writing the `JOIN` and `WHERE` conditions yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using PHP frameworks such as [CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org/) or [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/), you will have to create your own query to fetch related data.

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_roles ON users.user_role_id = users_roles.id
```

After that you can fetch the records and use them in your code.